# Bitcoin protocol using socket (java)

Tags: java, sockets, networking, protocols, bitcoin

I develop bitcoin protocol using socket, but met some issues. Firstly, when my code connects to bitcoin node, it doesn't give any response. I send version message, but another side node doesn't re-send anything. I think that problem could be that I implement protocol wrong, but I checked and think that it's fine. (2) Secondly, I think that could be impossible connect to bitcoin node using socket, but it's stupid idea. Yea?

One important thing, I coded only socket connection, version sending to bitcoin node, which I found on https://bitnodes.earn.com/nodes/ , and message receiving from node, but it always responses -1.
One more thing, I don't give response from node, but also don't give connection error. (I just say)

Please help me :)

What is wrong that I send version message, but then doesn't give another one from node?

Also, I attach output (connection phases and protocol structure) of console when try to connect to socket.

```
Connected
f9beb4d976657273696f6e0000000000000000660a75c8397f1101000100000000000000820b905c00000000010000000000000000000000000000000000ffff340e5966208d010000000000000000000000000000000000ffff7f000001208db910e81a17a5dd79102f417572696d61733a302e31362e332f0000000001
Magic:f9beb4d9
Command:76657273696f6e0000000000
Length:00000066
Checksum:0a75c839
Payload:7f1101000100000000000000820b905c00000000010000000000000000000000000000000000ffff340e5966208d010000000000000000000000000000000000ffff7f000001208db910e81a17a5dd79102f417572696d61733a302e31362e332f0000000001
Version:7f110100
Services:0100000000000000
timestamp:820b905c00000000
addr_recv:010000000000000000000000000000000000ffff340e5966208d
addr_from:010000000000000000000000000000000000ffff7f000001208d
nonce:b910e81a17a5dd79
user_agent:102f417572696d61733a302e31362e332f
start_height:00000000
relay:01
Connection end
```

Main class:

```
private static String address = "52.14.89.102";
    private static int port = 8333;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        String line = "";
        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            VersionMessage message = new VersionMessage();
            line = Hex.encodeHexString(message.getMessage());
            System.out.println(line);

            structure(message.getMessage());

            out.writeBytes(line);;
        } catch(UnknownHostException u) {
            System.out.println(u);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
...
```

The part of VersionMessage class:

```
public VersionMessage() {
        super();
        this.version = 70015;
        this.services = 1;                  // NODE_NETWORK
        this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        this.nonce = new Random().nextLong();
        this.userAgent = "/Satoshi:0.16.3/";
        this.startHeight = 0;
        this.relay = true;

        contructPayload();
        contructMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void contructPayload() {
        addByteArray(dataParser.toInt32(version));
        addByteArray(dataParser.toInt64(services));
        addByteArray(dataParser.toInt64(timestamp));
        addAddr("52.14.89.102", 8333);
        addAddr("127.0.0.1", 8333);
        addByteArray(dataParser.toInt64(nonce));
        addStr(userAgent);
        addByteArray(dataParser.toInt32(startHeight));
        addByteArray(dataParser.toInt8(relay ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0));

        payload = new byte[payloadBytes.size()];
        IntStream.range(0, payloadBytes.size()).forEach(i -> payload[i] = payloadBytes.get(i).byteValue());
    }
```

BitcoinMessage (parent of VersionMessage):

```
public BitcoinMessage() {
        magic = 0xf9beb4d9;;
        payloadBytes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        dataParser = new DataParser();
    }

    public void contructMessage() {
        message = new byte[MAGIC_LENGTH + COMMAND_LENGTH + PAYLOAD_LENGTH_SIZE + CHECKSUM_LENGTH + payload.length];

        length = payload.length;
        byte[] doubleHashedPayload = MessageUtils.doubleHashWithSha256(payload);

        MessageUtils.addToByteArray(MessageUtils.intToBytes(magic, MAGIC_LENGTH), 0, MAGIC_LENGTH, message);
        MessageUtils.addToByteArray(getCommandName().getBytes(), MAGIC_LENGTH, COMMAND_LENGTH, message);
        MessageUtils.addToByteArray(MessageUtils.intToBytes(length, PAYLOAD_LENGTH_SIZE),  MAGIC_LENGTH + COMMAND_LENGTH, PAYLOAD_LENGTH_SIZE, message);
        MessageUtils.addToByteArray(doubleHashedPayload, MAGIC_LENGTH + COMMAND_LENGTH + PAYLOAD_LENGTH_SIZE, CHECKSUM_LENGTH, message);
        MessageUtils.addToByteArray(payload,  MAGIC_LENGTH + COMMAND_LENGTH + PAYLOAD_LENGTH_SIZE + CHECKSUM_LENGTH, payload.length, message);
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to check your code without running it in debug step by step. I have wrote by myself class in C# which can do this. If you have an ability to debug C# code, you can compare 2 implementations.

Comment: I add project: https://github.com/nastae/bitcoin-protocol